# What download file do I need to get PyODBC 3.1.1 for Python 3.2?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I can't make head nor tail out of the wheelhouse install files for PyODBC.  There seem to be three parameters encoded in .whl file names at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/3.1.1 .  One appears to be a Python version number, and no file is listed for Python 3.2.  Another parameter is the processor, and I haven't the foggiest idea what the third parameter is.  This is the first time I've ever heard of a "wheelhouse" installation file.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: `3.1.1` is the version of the library, it has nothing to do with the Python version. Then comes the operating system & platform it's supposed to be run on.

Comment: None of these pre-built wheels are for CPython 3.2 - you could try `pip install pyodbc`as per their [documentation](http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/#installing) but you may have to build the library from source

Comment: It might be easier all around to simply upgrade from Python 3.2 to Python 3.5 and then use`pip` to install pyodbc (which should grab the appropriate wheel file).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you downloading wheel files from PyPI? Can't you use `pip`to install your packages? BTW, wheel files have been around for quite some years now, there's even a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) about them and [here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/27/python-on-wheels/) you can read a little about their history. I strongly advise you against manually downloading files from de Index, you should really use `pip` or set a cache server if you need to keep the packages.

Comment: Basically, nobody at my company has any real idea of how to use Python intelligently, beyond basic knowledge of the syntax.  I want to use PyODBC because we've been relying on COM and the Microsoft ADODB library for database access without bothering to see if there's anything better for about the last fifteen years.  I am not exaggerating.  I have spent far more time than I should have trying to work around that library's eccentricities.  I want to use PyODBC instead because I expect it to be easier to use and much more reliable.  But I've got an old version, and want to upgrade.

Comment: "pip install --upgrade pyodbc" in my Python32/scripts folder failed, complaining that a path cannot be absolute.

Comment: Can you show me the full output of the command? a simple `pip install pyodbc` should do the magic, provided that there's nothing wrong with your internet connection and you have the proper rights in the machine