# Python: pyodbc import module not found

Tags: python, oracle, odbc

I'm badly confused.  I have very little problem with the Python language, but setting up Python seems to be beyond me.

I have a Windows 7 machine.  I have installed the 64-bit version of Python 3.6 (more about why 64 bits later).  I need the pyodbc module.  I also have the 32-bit version of Python 3.5, and pyodbc is installed in its site-packages folder.  The first time I tried to get pyodbc for 3.6, pip told me the requirement was already fulfilled by the version in 3.5.  Then, I found the --ignore-installed option and successfully (?) installed it in my 3.6 folder.

When I open my project in PyCharm and select my 64-bit Python 3.6 as the interpreter, PyCharm shows me the pyodbc package.  But when I open the file in which pyodbc is imported, PyCharm highlights the import line and tells me it can't find pyodbc.  Just in case PyCharm was confused, I tried running my program from a command window, and got the same error.

Do I have to set an environment variable?  I didn't have one set when I used pyodbc in a project using Python 3.5, and I had no problem.

I am trying to use 64-bit Python because a customer requires us to write into their Oracle database.  They installed an ODBC driver for us, into their standard DSN list.  But since we installed a 32-bit version of Python on their system, the only DSNs it can see are those installed in the 32-bit list of DSNs.  If there is some easy way to use the 64-bit Oracle ODBC driver from 32-bit Python, I'd appreciate learning about it.

Thanks again.

Comment: At command line (CMD or PowerShell), type for each version of **python.exe**: `"C:\Path\To\python" -m pyodbc`. Which version errs on the module? In PowerShell you need to add `&` just before the quoted path.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In python 3.5 I get "No code object available for pyodbc", and in python 3.6 I get "No module named pyodbc".

Comment: With my Python interpreter set to 3.5, my pyocbc test program runs, even though the "import odbc" line is flagged as an error.  With the interpreter set to 3.6, the test program fails with "No module" error

Comment: For 3.6, you do not have pyodbc installed and for 3.5 it may have been incorrectly installed. At CMD or PowerShell, try installing to either: `"C:\Path\To\python" -m pip install pyodbc`. Might consider `uninstall` then re-install for 3.5.

Comment: For 3.5, I had a file in site-packages named pyodbc.cp35-win_amd64.pyd.  I copied it and renamed the copy to pyodbc.pyd, and it worked.  In 3.6, it did not work.  The error said that pyodbc.pyd required python35.dll.  The pyodbc download page has a file named pyodbc-4.0.3-cp36-dp36m-win_amd64.whl, but when I install that, I get an error saying the that is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Did you attempt the command? Going back to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291353/what-download-file-do-i-need-to-get-pyodbc-3-1-1-for-python-3-2), why are using .whl and not pip?

Comment: I wanted to get the pyodbc for Python 3.6.  The only available file for installing pyodbc for 3.6 was a .whl file.  I was trying to use pip to install the .whl file, which is supposed to be possible.  As far as I can tell, the wheel file name is specific to a certain combination of Python, Python editor, and operating system.  I do not know how to decode that name, but what I have on my computer does not match what the file name says I am supposed to have.  Any link to an explanation of the wheel file name would be appreciated.

Comment: Download your needed .whl here in [python windows binary extensions](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc). Be sure to select *cp36* and correct OS bit (32bit / 64bit).